# Explanation of Pkg's colors and symbols

Tags: julia

I've looked through the docs for the Julia Pkg manager, but I couldn't see on flipping through any examples or explanations of the symbols and colors.

[image: package manager]

I may be feeling more stupid than usual this morning, but...

Does the yellow up arrow say that there is an upgrade available, or that it has been upgraded, or could be upgraded, or should be upgraded? `up` doesn't change anything, and `st` gives the same information each time I run it.

The green + sign suggest that the package has been added, but why green not white? Or is it saying the package can be added? Or that the package should be added? `add` changes nothing, neither does `st`.

The red minus sign says to me "you should delete this package". Or does it mean "it has been deleted", or that "it doesn't work"?

The only part of this output I really understand is that the BenchmarkTools package is installed and has the version v0.4.2 (and same for the other ordinary-looking entries).

Is there an explanation somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A light yellow entry with an upward arrow `↑` means the package *has been* upgraded.

```
[31c24e10] ↑ Distributions v0.18.0 ⇒ v0.20.0
```

A light magenta entry with an downward arrow `↓` means the package *has been* downgraded.

```
[033835bb] ↓ JLD2 v0.1.2 ⇒ v0.1.1
```

A light green entry with a plus sign means the package *has been* added.

```
[c145ed77] + GenericSchur v0.2.3
```

A light red entry with a minus sign means the package *has been* removed.

```
[54eb57ff] - InteractiveCodeSearch v0.3.1
```

There are also light yellow entries with a tilde `~`. They appear if the version of the package does not change but you pin/unpin a package (with a pin indicator), or there are changes in the package path, or in the package repo (for example when you add a package from a branch like `add WebIO#master` and there is a new commit to the master branch).

```
[033835bb] ~ JLD2 v0.1.2 ⇒ v0.1.2 ⚲
```

You may also see red (not light red) entries with `?` sign. Such entries implies that an unknown operation has occurred. These probably indicate an error or a case which is not handled by `Pkg`.

You can see how these lines are produced [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Pkg.jl/blob/master/src/Display.jl#L171).

---

These outputs can appear both under `Updating .../Project.toml` and `Updating .../Manifest.toml`.

> - **Project file**: a file in the root directory of a project, named
>     `Project.toml` (or `JuliaProject.toml`) describing metadata about the
>     project, including its name, UUID (for packages), authors, license,
>     and the names and UUIDs of packages and libraries that it depends on.
> - **Manifest file**: a file in the root directory of a project, named
>     `Manifest.toml` (or `JuliaManifest.toml`) describing a complete dependency
>     graph and exact versions of each package and library used by a
>     project.

When you add or update a package, Julia will install or update not only the package itself but also its dependencies (also considering the dependencies of other packages).

When these lines may appear below `.../Project.toml` and indicate changes directly to your project and when under `.../Manifest.toml` these indicate change in your project manifest or your Pkg dependency graph.

---

The `st` or [`status`](https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/repl/#repl-status) Pkg commands will also show the changes to your project file since the last commit (if you are in a git repo). They do not show the available updates or such.

> why green not white?

Well, colors add distinction and the default terminal color is used for packages with no change in `status` and other things.

Comment: Thanks, this level of detail is really helpful...! :)  So the "has been" status is referring to a previous state - how long does that stay in "has been" status: ie. how long until green entries change to white (because "white" packages were presumably "green" once?)

Comment: @daycaster You use a git repo for your `Project.toml` and `Manifest.toml`. Since `status` shows the changes since the last commit, if you commit the changes then these will all turn to white without diff info. The diff entries will also disappear if you get rid of the git repo.

Comment: Oh, that make sense. So there's an extra level of updating going on, not just all the packages, but the versions of the `toml` files as well. Right, that explains a lot... :)

Comment: Yes, the status/changes in your project/environment are written to these files.

Comment: Great answer! It would be a nice addition to the docs to put this info in there somewhere.